# Calculate the sum of the dynamic Cells/Rows of excel column in WPF

Tags: wpf, excel

Please, is there any way at all to add up (sum up) the contents of the cells (Rows) of a given column whose number of possible rows (cells) are dynamic, that is, the number of rows are not fixed, in an excel worksheet? I've been trying without any meaningful result, i tried using offset but keep getting some COM_Exception from HRESULT blah blah......

Below is a part of a demo code am trying to use in achieving my purpose.

Please any suggestion(with a code snippet) will be highly appreciated.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

       {


        excel.Application xlApp;

        excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;

        excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;


        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;



        xlApp = new excel.Application();

        var MyExcel = new excel.Application();

        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);



        xlWorkSheet = (excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        excel.Range chartRange;
        chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("$A:$A", Type.Missing);

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Temperature(deg)";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Humidity(m-3)";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Wind Speed(m/s)";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = 33;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2] = 45;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 3] = 34;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1] = 23;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 2] = 26;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 3] = 43;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 1] = 45;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 2] = 24;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 3] = 34;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 1] = 40;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 2] = 32;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 3] = 42;



        decimal fdt = 0;
        int i = 2;

        excel.Range targetRange = (excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1];

        while (xlWorkSheet.Cells.Offset[i, 0].Value2 != null)
        {
            i++;
            fdt += xlWorkSheet.Cells.Offset[i, 0].Value2;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(fdt.ToString());

  excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
  excel.ChartObject myChart = (excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(400, 50, 400, 300);
  excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;      
  chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
  chartPage.ChartType = excel.XlChartType.xl3DColumnClustered;

  try
  {
      myChart.Chart.HasTitle = true;
      excel.Range objRange = (excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells["$A:$A", Type.Missing];

      String strData = objRange.get_Value(misValue).ToString();

      myChart.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = strData;


  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
  }

             xlWorkBook.SaveAs("DemoChart_1.xls", excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue,

    excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);


             xlApp.Visible = true;



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never Mind, i have been able to do it myself. And for anyone that might get stucked with this kind of problem like i was, here you go:

```
            int numRows = 0;
            double sum = 0;
            double Average = 0;
            excel.Range count = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns["A", misValue] as excel.Range;
            foreach (excel.Range cell in count.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.Value2 != null && cell.Value2 is double?)

                 {
                    sum += cell.Value2;
                    numRows += 1;
                }

            }


            Average = sum / numRows;
           txtAverage.Text = Average.ToString();
```

//the "&&" is very necessary so as to avoid adding a cell's value (which might be a string - like a column's header) to double, to avoid getting errors.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that `xlWorkSheet.Cells.Offset[i, 0].Value2` is valid. Instead of using `Offset`, just stick with `Cells(i, 1).Value2`. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but using your suggestion as: while (xlWorkSheet.Cells[i,1] != null) //where i = 2 and within the while loop {i++; targetRange.Value2+= xlWorkSheet.Cells[i,1].Value2; } gives me an empty output this time....i think i need to add a little effort to make this work the way i want it but don't actually know what to do yet. Am really stuck.

Comment: What column are you trying to sum? `Cells[i,1]` would be the 1st column ("A"). Also, you might try it without the `.Value2`, but I'll try it later today in WPF, as well. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, it is the first column that am trying to Sum. The i is to enable me iterate or loop through the rows of Column A. OK, I'll be patiently waiting for your feedback.

Comment: Try `(xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2` in your assignment statement. If that doesn't work, then try appending `.ToString()` after `Value2`, and if that still doesn't work, then I'll go back to the drawing board.

Comment: You might also try `xlWorkSheet.Range("A" + i).Value2`, I'm not able to test the code at this time. I'd consider creating a `Range` variable and assigning it the `UsedRange` of the worksheet, then iterating through that object. Hopefully someone else can weigh in on this, too, though.

Comment: I'll try your suggestions. Thanks a lot for your replies so far.

Comment: Microsoft.CSharp.RunTimeBinder.RunTimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference because it is a non-nullable value type. This is getting me mad!....I was able to get all the values on a single column inform of ($A:$A) and use them to plot a column graph, will it not be possible to get the sum of these items(values) using ($A:$A)?